# Best possible subset of data.frame without NA

Tags: r, algorithm, subset, na, large-data

I have data.frame of dim: 160560 x 171. There is a lot of data, but almost 90 % of it are NA.

The algorithm (lets call it ALG) which I willing to use do not tolerates any NA in data.frame. 
My idea is to find the best possible subset of this data.frame and use ALG on it.

What I have in my mind when I say subset? Subset with n columns ( n<171) of data.frame (which has 171 columns), which doesn't contain any NA (all rows are full).

What I have in my mind when I say the best? That subset have the most rows, that it possible can have. F.e. if I have two subsets of 20 columns, and the first have 1152 rows and the second - 2254, I choose second.

The problem is that simple combinatorics doesnt work there, because the result of combn(1:171,20) is more than 5*10^25.

Is there in R any library, which can help me to handle this problem?

Comment: Is 20 columns the minimum number you need in the subset?

Comment: 20 is just f.e. I'm willing to check ALG on different subsets (20col, 30col, 40col,....). It is obvious, that more col I take, the less row I get.

Comment: So there is no absolute minimum number of columns?

Comment: No, there is not

Comment: In that case you can simply select the column with the least number of NA (check `colSums(is.na(df))`)

Comment: That doesn't imply, that this subset is the best.

Comment: It does, you criterion is max number of rows, not max number of values.

Comment: Yeah, thats the criterion. But f.e. if I take 5 col which has the most values, it doesn't imply, that these collumns would be in the best subset of 20 collumn. Beceuse NA in data.frame are distributed extremly random - there are now rows, that don't have any NA.

Comment: F.e. my biggest collumns are: 51,64,79,111 and 142. But that doesn't imply, that the best subset (with 20 col) would contain 1:20 collumns

Comment: It's not clear if you want to keep all values from the rows in your subset, or if you will truncate values for columns 1-19 so they are the same length as column 20.

Comment: You either have to impose a restriction on the minimum number of columns or change your optimization criterion to maximum number of non-NA values across columns (not number of rows!)

Comment: Maybe a Genetic algorithm could help here? Permutation optimization?

Comment: It still stands that you will have the max rows by choosing a single column that has the least NAs. It is certain that your criterion, number of rows, can't increase by adding more columns (or choosing a different column).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it with `crossprod`. This will give you the columns that have maximum number of non-NA rows for a given number of columns. There's no going around it, you have to choose a number of columns to get. Otherwise, you'll always end up choosing a single column with the least NAs

First, let's create an initial matrix for this example. It has to be a matrix at this point. Use, `as.matrix` on your data as needed.

```
set.seed(2)
x <- runif(150)
x[sample(1:150, 15, replace = FALSE)] <- NA
x <- matrix(x,ncol=10)
round(x,1)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]  0.2  0.9  0.0  0.8  0.8  0.8  1.0  0.6  0.0   0.7
 [2,]  0.7  1.0  0.2  1.0  0.9  0.3  0.4  0.9  0.2   0.5
 [3,]  0.6  0.2  0.8  0.3  0.6  0.9  0.4  0.5   NA   0.8
 [4,]  0.2  0.4  0.9  0.5  0.3  0.4  0.6  0.1  0.9   0.2
 [5,]  0.9  0.1  0.5  0.8  0.9  0.6  0.5  0.1  0.2   0.4
 [6,]  0.9  0.7  0.6  0.0  0.4  0.4  0.2  0.0  0.8   0.2
 [7,]   NA  0.4  0.8  0.0  0.4  0.7  0.4  0.7  0.6   0.3
 [8,]  0.8  0.8  0.3  0.7  0.5  0.0  0.1  0.4  0.3   0.6
 [9,]  0.5  0.2  0.7   NA  0.2  0.4  0.1   NA  0.7   0.3
[10,]  0.5   NA  0.2  0.3  0.1  0.2  0.4  0.8  0.3    NA
[11,]  0.6  0.5   NA  0.8  0.3  0.9  0.2  0.8  0.2   0.7
[12,]   NA  0.1   NA  0.8  0.3  1.0  0.4  0.9   NA   0.7
[13,]  0.8   NA  0.1   NA  0.0  0.3  1.0   NA  0.0   0.3
[14,]  0.2  1.0  0.2  0.6  0.2  0.7   NA  1.0   NA   0.5
[15,]  0.4  0.1  0.9  0.7  0.2  0.3  0.3  0.6  0.3   0.3
```

As you can see, column 5 and 6 have no NAs

Now, let's create a similar matrix where NAs are 0 and non-NA are 1.

```
is_na_vector<- ifelse(is.na(x),0,1)
```

After that, let's calculate the `crossproduct` :

```
crossprod_vector <- crossprod(is_na_vector)
colSums(crossprod_vector)
 [1] 119 120 119 120 135 135 127 120 111 127
```

As you can see, column 5 and 6 have the highest `colSums`. This means that, in combination with other variables, they have the least number of NAs

We then use that colSums vector to select a number of columns. This will rank all columns and give the `n` first. Here are the three columns with the maximum number of non-NA rows. In this case 14 rows. There can be ties at this point, but it should not be a problem when you select 20 columns.

```
n <- 3
x_df <- as.data.frame(x) #to get meaningful colnames
res <- x_df[,rank(-colSums(crossprod_vector),ties.method ="first")<=n ] #use "-" to get decreasing rank
res
          V5        V6        V7
1  0.7700279 0.7554624 0.9767552
2  0.8869842 0.2880597 0.3970164
3  0.6251217 0.8678447 0.3799989
4  0.2603000 0.4026427 0.5603876
5  0.8590731 0.5726850 0.4638082
6  0.4374880 0.3506426 0.1967768
7  0.3881448 0.6719989 0.4269434
8  0.4615011 0.0250504 0.0930252
9  0.2186752 0.4011010 0.1153091
10 0.0659355 0.1999765 0.4400317
11 0.2757010 0.8565250 0.2009347
12 0.3103811 0.9715154 0.4276391
13 0.0421755 0.3237224 0.9806000
14 0.1846735 0.7331914        NA
15 0.1833732 0.3400682 0.2869739
```

Use `na.omit` to get non-NA rows:

```
na.omit(res)
          V5        V6        V7
1  0.7700279 0.7554624 0.9767552
2  0.8869842 0.2880597 0.3970164
3  0.6251217 0.8678447 0.3799989
4  0.2603000 0.4026427 0.5603876
5  0.8590731 0.5726850 0.4638082
6  0.4374880 0.3506426 0.1967768
7  0.3881448 0.6719989 0.4269434
8  0.4615011 0.0250504 0.0930252
9  0.2186752 0.4011010 0.1153091
10 0.0659355 0.1999765 0.4400317
11 0.2757010 0.8565250 0.2009347
12 0.3103811 0.9715154 0.4276391
13 0.0421755 0.3237224 0.9806000
15 0.1833732 0.3400682 0.2869739
```

You can see how many non-NA rows you get with `nrow`:

```
nrow(na.omit(res)) #14
```

For `n <- 5`, I get 12 non-NA rows